# Edit state of every item of a FlatList

Tags: react-native, state, react-native-flatlist

I made a page in which I use a FlatList. This FlatList uses an item component I made that display another view below itself when pressed by setting a state "hidden" to false. The main issue I have is that I can't find a way to change the "hidden" state to true when one of the item is pressed, hence always keeping only 1 item displaying the additional view at the time. In the same time, when I refresh/re-render my FlatList, it does not set all the "hidden" state back to true.

This is where I render my FlatList

```
_onRefresh() {
    this.setState({refreshing: true}, () => this._loadList());
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={[style.container, style.whiteBackground]}>
            <CategoryFilter filterCallback={this._changeCategory}/>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.list}
                extraData={this.state}
                renderItem={({item}) =>
                    <ListItemComponent item={item} category={this.state.category}/>
                }
                refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                onRefresh={() => this._onRefresh()}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

And this is where I render and display the hidden view

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        hidden: true
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({hidden: true});
}

_onPress() {
    this.setState({
        hidden: !this.state.hidden
    });
}

[...]

_renderOS(item) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        return (
            <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => this._onPress()}>
                {this._renderItem(item)}
            </TouchableNativeFeedback>
        );
    } else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPress()}>
                {this._renderItem(item)}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

[...]

_renderDescription(item) {
    if (this.state.hidden === true) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (
            <View style={listItemStyle.descriptionContainer}>
                <Text style={listItemStyle.description}>
                    {item.description}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I just want to be able to have only one of the list item with hidden set to false at the time and have said item to be set to hidden=true when the page is refreshed, but I never found anything that could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after thinking a lot I finally found a solution.
Instead of handling the hidden state in every item, I made a list of every hidden state associated to the items ids in the component where my flatlist is, adding a function that will set the previously opened item to hidden and open the new one, and passing it as a callback to my items so that it can be called when I press them.

```
_onPress(id) {
    let items;

    items = this.state.items.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === this.state.openId)
            item.open = false;
        else if (item.id === id)
            item.open = true;
        return item;
    });
    this.setState({
        items: items,
        openId: (id === this.state.openId ? '' : id)
    });
}

            <FlatList
                data={this.state.items}
                extraData={this.state}
                renderItem={({item}) =>
                    <ListItemComponent
                        onPress={this._onPress.bind(this)}
                        bet={item}
                        categoryList={this.state.categoryList}
                        open={item.open}/>
                }
                refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                onRefresh={() => this._onRefresh()}
            />
```